# Can someone tell me why this video playback is failing

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the link to it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45Akn/9/

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
   height="340px" 
   width="590px" 
   id="live_embed_player_flash" 
   data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel={ongamenet}" 
   bgcolor="#000000">
   <param  name="allowFullScreen" 
      value="true" />
   <param  name="allowScriptAccess" 
      value="always" />
   <param  name="allowNetworking" 
      value="all" />
   <param  name="movie" 
      value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
   <param  name="flashvars" 
      value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel={ongamenet}&auto_play=true" />
</object>
enter code here
```

The video is failing to load and I'm not quite sure why, would you be willing to take a look at it? I'm thinking it might be an authentication problem?

ok I got it to work by changing this:

```
 data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel={ongamenet}" 
       bgcolor="#000000">
```

to this

http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?day9tv

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output from my console when I run the (js)fiddle:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/%7Bongamenet%7D/viewer?as3=t
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/%7Bongamenet%7D?as3=t
>
> GET https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/%7Bongamenet%7D?as3=t 404 (Not Found) %7Bongamenet%7D:1
>
> GET https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/%7Bongamenet%7D/viewer?as3=t 404 (Not Found) viewer:1

The code requests something that doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `{ }` from the channel name.

```
data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel={ongamenet}" << HERE
value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel={ongamenet}&auto_play=true" /> << AND HERE
```

so it would just be `ongamenet` and not `{ongamenet}`